# Blazor WebApp, Blazored.TextEditor events not working

Tags: events, nuget-package, blazor-webassembly, rich-text-editor, blazored

I'm using Blazored.TextEditor component and I need to know if the user is typing something and when he stopped. I found on the github three events, one of them being OnTextChange and it would work perfectly for me. I have the most recent version of the NuGet package but it seems that the event isn't there. Anyone knows why? Or how could I achieve the same behavior without this event?